# Heroku Dyno Free Hours

Tags: heroku, dyno

So I have deployed a telegram bot through Heroku. For now I have 550 hours (I have only this app). If i verify my credit card I can get a total of 1000 hours. So... with one app and 1000 hours my app will be forever online right?(excluding the sleeping after 30 minutes, but with Kaffeine I think that I can make it forever online). Just to be sure... I know that after a 30 minutes of inactivity the app will sleep. So even if I use the bot for 1 sec it will consumes 30 minutes; if one user uses the bot at 15.30 and another one at 15.40, it will consume 30 minutes or 60 minutes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku charges by wall-clock time, so for all minutes your dyno is up.

When a request comes at h14:00 the applications starts, shutting down at h14:30 if there is no further usage after that single request, **total 30 min**

When a second request comes at h14:15 the application is already up and running, shutting down at 14:45 if there is no further usage after the second request, **total 45 min**

During the activity (which you are charged for) the app can serve multiple requests without incurring in additional costs.